# Is there still any supported Eclipse Application\version? (for maintaining old projects)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have some old projects developed in Eclipse which I don't really want to "waste" time on migrating to Android Studio (some I have just failed to migrate).

Is there still any supported Eclipse Application\version?

Comment: `any supported Eclipse` as I know - there are none. Only legacy ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have understood that there is no support on any Eclipse version anymore.
I have migrated all my projects to Android Studio and all is well :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can import your projects build in Eclipse to Android Studio. Just Follow below steps

1. GoTO File >> New >> Import Project
2. Select Project and Click OK - Android Studio will create new project using Eclipse project data.

**Optional**

3. If your Eclipse Project has any jar files you can add them in app folder of Android Studio Project
4. Then Open you Android Studio Project as Project View and inside app folder, Right click on jar file and select add as library.